# Publishing message only if listener exist?

Tags: javascript, php, rabbitmq

using RabbitMQ, I'd like my (PHP) code to publish a message to a specific customer only if this specific user is currently listening.

The reason for that is that my connected user will open a websocket that will wait for notifications from RabbitMQ and update the UI when notifications arrive. But when they first load the page, all the previous notification will be loaded so there is no need to reload notification that are in the queue.

Being new to Message queuing, I don't know if it's possible, but I'd like my publisher to check if user ID = X is currently listening (since the websocket will open a channel when being executed), and if he's currently listening, posting a message. If he's not, then it won't post that message (but add it in the database).

The workflow is like this :

Publisher :

1. The endpoint is receiving an event
2. It save the event in the database
3. It check if user ID =X has an open channel, if yes, it publish the event to that channel

Subscriber :

1. The customer connects to the app
2. The frontend loads the last events from the database
3. The frontend opens a websocket for that specific user that listen to events that may be published
4. When events are published, the websocket tells the frontend.

Maybe what I'm asking is basic, but I lack the knowledge to tell.

**One bonus question** : Is it better to open a channel PER customer, or open a generic channel for all customer, that the subscribe side will filter ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Doesn't this requirement make the whole AMQP protocol redundant? I mean: the point of AMQP is that you can produce a message, regardless of where/who/when consumes it. Wanting to know whether or not a specific consumer is up might be best handled using a webservice approach (API calls, micro-service architecture)

Comment: That's the current working version of my structure (if I understand your comment correctly) : The frontend queries every 5 seconds the backend to see if there is new changes, and applies them if they exists. The idea behind websocket is to reduce these queries, because with one connected user, it's ok, but with 500 (arbitral number), it will be more difficult to handle.

Comment: So you want to use rabbitMQ in the front-end, to see if the backend published some changes, or is it the other way around (blocking produce/consume, replacing the queries)? Wouldn't it be possible to use a NoSQL solution into which the backend stores the data, and have the frontend fetch it? Redis.io or Couchbase spring to mind, both have php extensions and are extremely fast. Kafka might also be worth a look (in tandem with ReactPHP or node.js backend), Though not stable, [I'm working on a PHP extension ATM](https://github.com/EVODelavega/phpkafka)

Comment: Not really (sorry if I wasn't clear). I have a webhook endpoint that is called from an external service when event occurs. That endpoint add the event to the database and would call the MQ service if the user is listening to. Then, there is the websocket side, used by the user, that would send a message to the frontend when a message is published by the endpoint. The frontend is in JS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are running into your question because there is a distinction within AMQP between publisher and queue.  There is not a one-to-one correspondence between the two.

If I understand your situation correctly, you have a central publisher that is firing messages off to the message broker.  At the same time, you have a number of potential subscribers who are signing on and off of the broker (via websockets in this case).  One of these subscribers is a database process, which archives all messages for later retrieval.

What I recommend is the following:

1. Publish these messages to a topic-style exchange
2. Subscribing consumers each create their own queue upon subscription. This would be done in the web server code, and it would funnel arriving messages to the websocket.
3. When creating subscription queues (dynamically), set the queues to auto-delete after a (short) number of seconds, so small interruptions in connectivity do not cause lost messages.
4. Create a persistent queue for the messages going to the database process(es).
5. It shall be the responsibility of the consuming application to de-duplicate between messages loaded from the database, and messages flowing in through the websocket. Assigning each message a `guid` should help with this.

To answer your second question, it depends on your web server architecture. I do not know enough about PHP, but in terms of the AMQP protocol itself, there is no impact. Channels are simply protocol-level constructs, so creating them is negligible in impact.  Multiple consumers can share one channel, or you can create a channel per consumer. It really makes no difference.